# Java convert system's current date-time to a count of seconds from epoch reference

Tags: java, facebook

I am using **Facebook query language** (FQL) to retrieve users dates. My FQL is as follows.

```sql
SELECT post_id , message 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = me() 
AND actor_id = me() 
AND created_time > 1221596000
```

Here I feel the **created_time** is in seconds.

I am using Java. Can anyone say me how to **convert systems current date and time** to the **created_time** seconds in Java?

Comment: What is the format of created_time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) is epoch in millisecond. So, given a second is a thousand millisecond. You could easily convert this by dividing `1000`. Or I am missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

divide this `System.currentTimeInMillis()` by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now() 
       .getEpochSecond()
```

> 1519944626

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

### Count-from-epoch

You can determine the number of **whole seconds from the epoch reference** of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z. Beware of data loss: You are ignoring any fractional second that may be residing in your `Instant` object’s value.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = instant.getEpochSecond() ;  // Ignores any fractional second in your `Instant`.
```

### Parsing

Your can go the other direction, parsing such a count-from-epoch into an `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( yourCountFromEpochGoesHere ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).